# jQuery closure function and resize event

Tags: jquery

How to call a closure function when resizing the screen?

I have the following construction:

```
(function() {
 // code
})(jQuery, false)
```

How do I get this function to restart on window resize?

```
$(window).on('load resize', function () {
 // restart closure
});
```

Or is there a way to call a nested function?

```
(function() {
 var n = function() {
  }
})(jQuery, false)
```

The source: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxWaOK
What I need is to reset the width of the picture on resize.

Comment: Restart a closure? Why not just put your `$(winodw).on()` inside the closure?

Comment: I think you have your vocabulary mixed up. This `(function () {})()` is not a "closure function", it's an "immediately executed function expression" (IIFE). Every function in JS creates a closure, that's nothing special.

Comment: Also, as a general tip: Looking at your [codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxWaOK), it's terribly confusing with all those one-letter variable- and function names. Try not to write code that looks like it went through a minimizer that just forgot to remove the whitespace.

Comment: @Artem Z Don't forget to accept one of the answer if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You have to name the function you wanna call several times.

```
(function() {
  var fn = function(jQuery, yourbool) {
    // put the code here
  };

  fn(jQuery, false);

  $(window).on('load resize', function () {
    fn(jQuery, false);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

This function style is an anonymous function automatically executed. This kind of functions cannot be called and are executed only once.

```
(function(/*Param given to the function*/) {
 // code
})(jQuery, false); //<-- This values are the parameters given to your function.
                   //    In your case, you don't need parameter or you should 
                   //    declare your parameters inside the brackets.
```

To reuse a function, you should declare it in the same scope and call it from event handler:

```
$(function() {
    function myFunction(evt) {
        console.log(evt);
    }

    $(window).on('load resize', myFunction);
});
```